# mincha during a meal

Tags: halacha, bentching, hefsek-interruption, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If you are in the middle of a meal you have not yet finished, and you realized that you are running late to mincha, would praying mincha before saying birkat hamazot be considered a hefsek?

Can you continue the same meal after Minch but before the 72 minutes pass?

What should a person do in such a case?

Comment: I read in a book about brachos that it is not a problem to daven in the middle of the meal and continue eating or say birkat hamazon afterwards as long as you never leave the room. Unfortunately, i don't remember what book it was (pretty sure it was in English)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Maharam Chalawa in the 10th chapter of Pesachim discusses this.  He says that even if it were coming down to the end of zman Mincha and you *had* to stop to daven, it would still not be a hefsek.

This is codified by the Shulchan Aruch O.C. 178:6

> מי שנזכר בתוך הסעודה שלא התפלל ועמד והתפלל אפילו אם אין שהות לגמור סעודתו ולהתפלל שחייב להפסיק ואי אפשר לו לאכול עד שיתפלל עם כל זה לא הוי הפסק

Comment: Daniel's comment above makes a mention about leaving the room--does this have any halachic weight?

Comment: @Ani Nothing on this site has halachic weight.

Comment: IIRC, there are some issues around Netilas Yadayim in doing that (A machlokes if you have to wash again).